# Tesseract example code error

Tags: tesseract

I am trying to run a test program for tesseract in eclipse to further create a java app. When i execute the following program:
import java.io.File;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;

public class TesseractExample {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File imageFile = new File("eurotext.tif");
    Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();  // JNA Interface Mapping
    //Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1(); // JNA Direct Mapping

    try {
        String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (TesseractException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

the errors generated are:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at net.sourceforge.vietocr.ImageIOHelper.getIIOImageList(ImageIOHelper.java:243)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:166)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:151)
at TesseractExample.main(TesseractExample.java:13)
```

All the libraries have been included in the class path including the support for pdf images. Help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems in Windows with Tesseract1 (I am not sure if the exact problem was that one but Tesseract1 never worked in Windows, while Tesseract did). I moved to Ubuntu Linux 12 32-bits and both classes worked fine (had to compile Tesseract, though).